# C++ program running as Apache CGI program cannot access shared memory via shmget

Tags: c++, apache, cgi

Apache CGI processes apparently can't create shared memory?  shmget() will return EACCES, permission denied error.  Anybody know how I can get past this?  I'm running on Linux (Fedora 17 w/ 3.9.10-100 kernel) and Apache 2.2.23.  This is on a closed system, so I don't really care about security holes this might cause.

Here is a minimal CGI program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <errno.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Content-Type: text/plain" << endl << endl;

  if(shmget(0x1234, 1000, IPC_CREAT | 0666) < 0) {
    cout << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "Success!" << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the minimal HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
  <form action="/cgi-bin/sscce" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Go" id="submit"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the result on command line:

```
$ ./run
Content-Type: text/plain

Success!
$ ipcs -m
------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status
0x00001234 29917185   root       666        1000       0
$ ipcrm -m 29917185
$
```

And here is the result running via Apache:

```
Content-Type: text/plain

Error: Permission denied
```

It's returning EACCES.  Other CGI stuff works just fine.  So, things I tried:

- changed Apache to run as same user as on the command line (no help)
- "chmod +s" on executable to run with root permissions (no help)
- "setcap cap_ipc_owner+iep" on executable (and also on httpd executable) since manpage for shmget() says it requires CAP_IPC_OWNER capability or will return EACCES (no help)

I'm a bit at my wits end.  Somehow, Apache is stripping away the ability of a CGI script (even running as root) to create a chunk of shared memory?  Googling turns up a couple other folks who have experienced this problem, but no solutions.  Also, the same thing happens if I pre-create the shared memory...  shmget() returns EACCES when just trying to connect to read from shared memory w/ permission of 0666.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally discovered the answer myself.  The problem is SELinux.  In /var/log/messages:

```
SELinux is preventing <executable> from using the sys_resource capability.
```

Turning off SELinux by editing /etc/sysconfig/selinux allows a CGI process to use shmget() succcesfully.  However, I am not aware of the full ramifications of turning off SELinux.  On our closed system, I don't think it is a big deal, but there is a probably a smaller hammer solution to this for other situations.  But this is the general direction to head.  Hope it helps someone sometime.